# How do i add to a mutable string in objective c?

Tags: string, character, addition, mutable

Without getting into to much detail about the actual program,I want to take an existing string and add more characters(or strings) to it. If this were done in java it would be like this

String x= "hello"

x= x + "world";

I currently have my string trying to do that like this. My string declared is called _whatiscorrect, it is an empty string right now and in this example i want to take the existing string and add an "o" to it.

_whatiscorrect = [_whatiscorrect stringByAppendingString:@"o"]; // place an o in the string

How do i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. Just do this:

```
NSMutableString * _whatiscorrect = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString: @".."];
[_whatiscorrect appendString:@"o"];
```